# saparate object to array of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i dont know how to make for loop to create new array of object with javascript coding

here i have some object like this

```
item :[
{
 res_name: 'a',
 id: 1,
 name: name1
},
{
 res_name: 'b',
 id: 2,
 name: name2
},
{
 res_name: 'b',
 id: 3,
 name: name3
}
]
```

i want to change to array of object like this

```
product:[
{
   res_name: 'a',
   product:[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: name1
    }
   ]
},
{
   res_name: 'b',
   product:[
    {
      id: 2,
      name: name2
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: name3
    }
   ]
}
]
```

can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over `items` and construct `products` obj .

```js
var item=[{res_name: 'a', id: 1, name: 'name1'},{res_name:'b', id: 2, name: 'name2'},{ res_name: 'b', id:3, name: 'name3'}];

var products=[];

item.forEach(function(element) {
   let obj = {};
   obj.products={};
   obj['products'].id=element.id;
   obj['products'].name=element.name
   obj['res_name']=element['res_name'];
   products.push(obj);
});


console.log(products);
```